# In TypeScript, why are Symbols for Privacy throwing errors for Consumers?

Tags: typescript, symbols, privacy

i wish for some privacy for some of my class fields and methods

- i know symbols aren't *really really* private, but i just don't want the "private" members just floating around for people to easily use, this is about signalling intent
- the typescript "private" keyword doesn't do anything to signal intent for privacy, neither by adding an underscore prefix nor by using symbols (not even as an option)
- i don't want to wait around for typescript to implement the private fields `#` proposal nor switch to babel now over this

here in my project [quizzly](https://github.com/chase-moskal/quizzly/blob/master/source/components/quizzly-quiz.ts#L19) i have created some classes which use symbols to access the private members

the pattern is basically:

```
const _counter = Symbol()

export class CountingThing {
  private [_counter] = 0
}
```

i thought this is a nice way to implement privacy until typescript finally incorporates the `#` private field syntax — this works nicely for a javascript-only npm consumers

unfortunately, this pattern doesn't seem to work for *typescript* consumers of my package

my ***consumer*** project gets these errors during typescript compilation:

```
node_modules/quizzly/dist/components/quizzly-question.d.ts:8:13 - error TS1166: A computed property name in a class property declaration must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

8     private [_getChoices];
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/quizzly/dist/components/quizzly-question.d.ts:8:14 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '_getChoices'.

8     private [_getChoices];
              ~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/quizzly/dist/components/quizzly-quiz.d.ts:26:13 - error TS1166: A computed property name in a class property declaration must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

26     private [_getSlottedElements];
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/quizzly/dist/components/quizzly-quiz.d.ts:26:14 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '_getSlottedElements'.

26     private [_getSlottedElements];
```

but why on earth would the consumer be complaining about **private** variables, which the consumer shouldn't even have any knowledge about at all?

oddly, the quizzly project itself reports no errors during typescript compilation, this only affects consumers using the `.d.ts` files

what strategies are available in typescript today, to implement some semblance of privacy?

Comment: i have a suspicion that i just need to export every symbol... not that i want access to these to be so easy :/

Comment: If these are private, why are they in `.d.ts` at all?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — yest that is an excellent question — the fact that there is any complaint from the consumer about anything private seemed immediately odd to me — take a look at the [quizzly-quiz.d.ts](https://unpkg.com/quizzly@0.0.0-dev.0/dist/components/quizzly-quiz.d.ts) versus the sourcecode [quizzly-quiz.ts](https://github.com/chase-moskal/quizzly/blob/master/source/components/quizzly-quiz.ts#L19) — is this a typescript bug, or is just confusing to my intuitions here?

Comment: The `.d.ts` output looks right: it has all the expected `declare const _x: unique symbol` declarations to match the `private [_x];` in the class declarations. And yes, those are intentional. How are you consuming this class?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens — but if you look at the source code, the `const`'s for the symbols are *never exported,* and the private fields on the class are *not public* — considering a `.d.ts` is supposed to describe the *public signature* of a module, this output we're seeing doesn't make sense — these things are not a part of the module's public signature, so why are they present in the `.d.ts` at all? this project is consumed like other npm packages, either via commonjs or via es modules (i prefer the latter however i provide both)

Comment: TypeScript puts the private fields into the `.d.ts` so you cannot accidentally override a private field in a subclass with `class Foo extends CountingThing`. Of course, that'll never happen in your case, since you don't export those symbols. Anyway, that still doesn't explain those type errors... I don't see those when I `import {CountingThing} from './dist/CountingThing'` from another project. :-/

Comment: Another possible workaround: add `/** @internal */` to all your private fields and set `"stripInternal": "true"` in your `tsconfig`. That'll make the compiler strip out those fields, so that (hopefully) gets rid of the errors. Not an ideal solution though...

Comment: @MattiasBuelens -- i find that workaround very interesting!

Comment: i have found that exporting all of the symbols fixes the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> neither by adding an underscore prefix nor by using symbols (not even as an option)

I disagree. `_foo` vs. `foo` feels very private to me. Its been a pattern in JavaScript for a long long time (2007).

> the typescript "private" keyword doesn't do anything to signal intent for privacy,

It works for TypeScript consumers just fine. JavaScript consumers know of `_`, at least if they use any other pure JS projects that compile down to es5 (a vast majority)

## My Suggestion

`private _something`

Comment: you know what, that's obviously the best way to do this... forget this symbol stuff 

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to export every symbol

```
const _counter = Symbol()

// the export keyword must be added

export const _counter = Symbol()
```

This resolves the typescript errors for the consumer

It does however, increase the availability of those symbols, making it easier for consumers to use them as they appear in the module's public signature